# Action_Call doesn't work with Galaxy S3?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

My problem is when I try to make a phone call using Action_Call intent, the app crashes and exits to menu. I have tested my code on many another devices and it worked fine! What is the problem? This is my code:

```
    String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
    String ussd = "*" + encodedHash + "105" + encodedHash;
    startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL",
    Uri.parse("tel:" + ussd)), 1);
```

Remember my problem is only on Galaxy S3 and I am also using Mono for Android.

Comment: The exception will probably reveal more info, use try .. catch